# Running an elevated process as a standard user

Tags: visual-studio, uac, process-elevation

Let us assume that there are two accounts in my system - one administrator and the other one a standard user.

I have noticed that when a standard user attempts to start a program, say command prompt, with elevated privileges, the UAC asks for the credentials of the admin and then starts the process. 
When this happens, in the task manager, it displays that the process is elevated but runs in the Admin account(under the user name column).

Is there any way to start a process with elevation from a standard user account and still display the User name as the Standard User's name and not the administrator's?